# In Robot Framework, in the test case teardown phase, how to check whether the current test case is fail or pass?

Tags: python, robotframework, testcase, test-framework, teardown

In Robot Framework test case, we can create `Teardown` phase to do clean-up activities.

```
| *Test Case* |
| testcase1 |
|    | [Setup] | Setup Actions |
|    | Do Something | Args |
|    | Do Something | Args |
|    | [Teardown] | Teardown Actions |

| *Keyword* |
| Teardown Actions |
|    | Do Something | Args |
|    | Do Something | Args |
```

---

In the `Teardown` phase, how can we check whether the current test case is Pass or Fail?

I would like to do something when the test case Pass, and do something else when the test case Fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a variable called `${TEST_STATUS}` that you can use in a teardown. This is documented under the section [Automatic Variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#automatic-variables) in the user guide.

You can also use keywords such as [Run keyword if test passed](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html?r=2.8.4#Run%20Keyword%20If%20Test%20Passed) and [Run keyword if test failed](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/libraries/BuiltIn.html?r=2.8.4#Run%20Keyword%20If%20Test%20Failed), which also only work in a teardown.